# How to deal with single quotes and untranslatable characters

Tags: sas, teradata

My SAS table contains a text column that has sentences. Some of these sentences contain single quotes somthing like `don't , space's . .` .Whenever i try to upload this table to teradata it throws an error `string contains untranslatable characters`

When i remove the `'` manually, it gets uploaded okay .

How can I upload the original sentences correctly in the original way ?

---

I suspect that this is not a regular single quote

I tried

```
varName = tranwrd(varName, "'",""); /* i also tried using ` instead of '  */
```

AND

```
varName = translate(varName, "","'"); /* i also tried using ` instead of '  */
```

But the string dod not change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility: instead of removing it manually, 'cut' it, and paste that into SAS instead of typing the ' or ` characters.

More generally, you can identify what a character actually is by looking at the `$HEX.` version of the character.

One good approach is to first remove known 'good' characters.

```
data want;
set have;
step1 = compress(yourvar,,'ns');
put step1= $HEX.;
run;
```

That removes (English) letters and numbers, underscores, and space-type characters (space, tab, etc.).  That should reduce your string to a relatively small number of characters; if you want to limit it further, add characters to the (currently missing) second argument.

Now, you can look at the hex output and identify what the character is, hopefully fairly easily.  Every 2 hex characters map to one ASCII character, unless you're in a Unicode environment, where that may not be the case (it may be 2, it may be as many as 8).  You should be able to see the 'bad' character.  Once you do find it, you can use `'##'x` to construct a character identical to it, and use `compress` to remove it (`compress` does what you're trying to do with `translate` more efficiently).  IE, if you have `'0A'x` (line feed), you could use

```
data want;
set have;
fixed=compress(yourvar,'0A'x);
run;
```

to remove the unwanted line feed.

Comment: Thank you. How can I remove all `untranslatable` characters ? Is it `myVar = tranwrd(myVar , compress(myVar ,,'ns'), "")`

Comment: `compress` removes characters, you don't need `tran`anything.  What is an untranslatable character is hard to define, however.  Look at your data, see what's in it.

Comment: It is a `'` . It looks exactly like all other `'`.  When I user `tranwrd` it works for all observations except for this one .

Comment: Read my answer and implement that.  Then come back and tell us what hex code maps to the apparent apostrophe.  What something looks like on the screen is unimportant compared to what is behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me, I don't know teradata but if it's problematic in the same way as sql. Convert your text from something like

```
'don't'
```

to

```
'don''t'
```

This may help

Comment: This is good advice, but if `translate` doesn't remove it, that's probably not the problem (assuming it was implemented correctly).